# Apps Scripts - data not writing to correct column

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using a script I found on Gitlab (https://github.com/g-r3m/GASapprovalGoogleFormworkflow/blob/main/DoGet.gs)

I want the data to write into column 7, not column 5. I think it is tied to line 48.
I believe the getRange values are as follows:  getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
Note:  var last = sh.getLastRow() so it does not call a specific row.

```
if (state === APPROVED_STATE) {
    var rangeApprove = sheet.getRange(last, 5, 1, 1);
    Logger.log('rangeApprove: ' + rangeApprove.getA1Notation());
    rangeApprove.setValues([
      [emailsession + ' on: ' + dateForLogging]
    ]);
  }
```

I've tried changing int 5 to 7, but data is still writing into column 5.
I'm quite new at this which is why I'm reusing someone else's script to help me learn.
Thank you!

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, for example, how about `sheet.getRange(last, 7).setValue(emailsession + ' on: ' + dateForLogging)`? In this case, the value of `emailsession + ' on: ' + dateForLogging` is put into column "G". By the way, about `I've tried changing int 5 to 7, but data is still writing into column 5.`, if you run your script as Web Apps with `doGet`, when you modify your script, please reflect your latest script to your Web Apps. I'm worried that the reason for your current issue might be related to this. How about this?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I apologize if I wasn't able to correctly articulate my problem. Yes, I want the data to write to column "G", not column "E". I understood the second int in the getRange (the 5) to dictate that action.

I just tried sheet.getRange(last, 7).setValue(emailsession + ' on: ' + dateForLogging) and had the same results. Data still writing to column "E".

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I just tried sheet.getRange(last, 7).setValue(emailsession + ' on: ' + dateForLogging) and had the same results. Data still writing to column "E".`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. As I have already mentioned in my 1st comment, I'm worried that in your situation, the latest script might not be reflected in your Web Apps. How about this?

Comment: I'm sorry, if you mean Google Web Apps, I am not using that. This google sheet is linked to a google form. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for replying. And, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand your reply.

Comment: I am not using Web Apps. I am using Google Forms. But I understand my post may not be very clear, but I appreciate you trying to help! Thank you!!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `I am not using Web Apps. I am using Google Forms.` and your showing question and your referred script, I'm confused to understand your situation. I apologize for this. But, I would like to support you. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: Hi. To clarify what Tanaike means, if at any point you hit Deploy after writing the code and create a new deployment, any changes you make to the code must be followed by a new deployment. The function `doGet()` implies that this is being called from a web app using something like `https://script.google.com/.../exec?request=something` but you did not explain how you actually start your code. If you did press the deploy button in the script editor to get started then do it again after you made your changes and see if that helps